# Pass parameters to Angular7 app without SystemJS

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 7 app which is added to a web page (Asp.net MVC5) using the root component selector, and referencing all JS and CSS files generated by the ng build.

So far the only way I found to sen parameters to an Angular app, is to:

- Use system js to pass parameters to the main.js class
- Use a cookie
- Use a javascript object globally available
- Attribute value then retrieved using elementRef
- for .net Core see: https://elanderson.net/2017/10/pass-asp-net-core-appsettings-values-to-angular

Is there another way to do it?

Why I am not happy:

1. I don't want to use SystemJS, I didn't need it so far and I rather avoid it
2. Using a cookie is an hacky approach and the cookie cannot be httponly which might lead to security issues
3. In 2019 I would really like to avoid global JS variables
4. Hacky approach that make it vulnarebla to XSS and difficult to handle types

I am trying to send a call to the server to retrieve data but I need to do in the main.ts, and this is making my task harder, because I struggle to inject the HttpClient with all dependencies.
I need the configuration in main.ts to initialize my JIT Translations (using i18n), TRANSLATIONS is provided in main.ts and not in the module or component.

Comment: Have you seen `Angular Elements`? They are still young (not yet as simple as they will be to use), but they are available to use. I found a post about using `Angular Elements` with MVC here: https://www.mithunvp.com/using-angular-elements-asp-net-core-angular-cli-visual-studio/ I'm not sure if it handles your parameter issue, but it may be worth checking out.

Comment: Thank you, it is a nice technology but there restrictions on browsers compatibility, and is not yet clear how i18n fits into it.